# Relay Modern Compiler Skips Generating File for Query Fragment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, relayjs, relaymodern

I'm building a simple news aggregator with React/Relay and I'm having issues with Relay Modern. Whenever I run the compiler it generates a FeatureRootQuery.graphql.js file. However, it doesn't generate a FeatureRow_viewer.graphql.js file for the corresponding fragment despite that fragment being included in the FeatureRootQuery.graphql.js file. The react app fails to compile because it cannot find the file. Anyone know what might be causing this?

FeatureRoot.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {
  QueryRenderer,
  graphql
} from 'react-relay';
import environment from '../Environment.js';
import FeatureRow from './FeatureRow';


class FeatureRoot extends Component {
  render() {
    const level = this.props.active;

    return (
      <QueryRenderer
        environment={environment}
        query={graphql`
          query FeatureRootQuery {
            ...FeatureRow_viewer
          }
        `}
        render={({error, props}) => {
          if (error) {
            return (<div>{error.message}</div>);
          } else if (props) {
            return (<FeatureRow viewer={props} level={level}/>)
          }
          return (<div>Loading</div>);
        }}
      />
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { active: state.level.active }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(FeatureRoot);
```

FeatureRow.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import FeatureCarousel from './FeatureCarousel';
import FeatureList from './FeatureList';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {
  createFragmentContainer,
  graphql
} from 'react-relay';
import '../styles/FeatureRow.css';


class FeatureRow extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      carouselImgHeight: 0,
      carouselTextHeight: 175,
      carouselHeight: 0
    };
    this.updateHeight = this.updateHeight.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.updateHeight();
  }

  updateHeight() {
    ...
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.updateHeight);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.updateHeight);
  }

  render() {
    let carouselArticles = this.props.viewer.sources[0].articles;
    let { level } = this.props;
    let { carouselHeight } = this.state;

    return (
      <div id="feature-row">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-sm-6 col-carousel">
            <FeatureCarousel
              level={level}
              articles={carouselArticles}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="col-sm-6 col-list">
            <FeatureList
              articles={carouselArticles}
              carouselHeight={carouselHeight}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


export default createFragmentContainer(
  FeatureRow,
  graphql`
    fragment FeatureRow_viewer on Query {
      sources(
        filter: {
          names: ["The New York Times", "The Washington Post", "The Wall Street Journal", "USA Today", "Associated Press", "Reuters"]
        }
      ) {
        id
        name
        articles {
          id
          author
          title
          description
          url
          urlToImage
          publishedAt
        }
      }
    }
  `,
);
```

Comment: Quick Update: I was able to generate the .graphql.js file by changing the file names to NewFeatureRoot and NewFeatureRow. Obviously, it's annoying to change the naming convention I've used throughout the project. So, I'm still hoping to find a solution that doesn't involve changing  file names and to understand why this happened. Hopefully, that info helps.